# Jenkins remove password from passed Parameters

Tags: jenkins

i have created a job in which user needs to enter his network password before building the job.
After building the job when I go to Build History
[image]

And then click on Parameters, the masked password of the user is visible on the page.
[image]

I am using Password parameter to get the Password from user.Is it possible to make it empty?

[image]

Comment: can you please confirm the parameter you are using in Jenkins configuration

Comment: Added to the question above